# Monodevelop 4.0 no codeview

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, monodevelop, kde4

I'm developing an application (http://sourceforge.net/projects/audiocuesheet/) and use fedora. Since the rpm for fedora is from monodevelop 2.8.x and I need the features of monodevelop 4.0. I downloaded the tarball and build monodevelop. It works good as described, but I can not view the source of my sourcefiles (screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone any idea, why this fails? I tried starting monodevelop with no redirection, but couldn't find any error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might by an issue with the oxygen-gtk-theme. See [here](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316995). Start Monodevelop with the environment variable OXYGEN_DISABLE_INNER_SHADOWS_HACK set to 1.

In the shell:

```
export OXYGEN_DISABLE_INNER_SHADOWS_HACK=1
monodevelop
```

You can also put this as a shell script to /usr/local/bin/monodevelop. Then monodevelop is automatically started with this environment variable.

```
#!/bin/sh
export OXYGEN_DISABLE_INNER_SHADOWS_HACK=1
/usr/bin/monodevelop
```

Remember to make it executable with `sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/monodevelop`

Answer (score 7):

It's a known bug.

The only solution (as for now) is to change your GTK theme in KDE settings -> Application Appearance.

They say (the bug has been filed somewhere) it's the problem with the theme itself, but I find it hard to believe... I guess you have oxygen-gtk set, change it to, for example, Raleigh, it will work.

Remember to restart monodevelop ;-)

I like oxygen theme, I find it the most annoying issue with md-4.0..

Edit:
http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Text-editor-problem-with-monodevelop-4-0-td4658742.html - here is where I've found the solution.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me. Is this a bug of monodevelop or gtk?

Comment: Well so this bug woun't be fixed since nobody is responsive?!

Comment: I think we can always try to reach the devs asking asking about what they think should be done about this issue - they ARE normal people and they ARE actively developing MD. And, well, it seems that there are at least two KDE users working on MD, so it's not gnome-only :)